# Having Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Не понятное поведение команды having для MySQL:

```
select  t.id as  id , t.val as val from
(
 select 1 id, 2 val union all
 select 2 id, 2 val union all
 select 3 id, 4 val union all
 select 4 id, 1 val union all
 select 5 id, 1 val union all
 select 6 id, 3 val
)t
having t.id>max(t.val)
;
```

Возвращает пустоту, прошу объяснить поведение

Comment: А разве **HAVING** работает без **GROUP BY**?

    SELECT t.id AS id, t.val AS val
    FROM (
        SELECT 1 id, 2 val UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 id, 2 val UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 id, 4 val UNION ALL
        SELECT 4 id, 1 val UNION ALL
        SELECT 5 id, 1 val UNION ALL
        SELECT 6 id, 3 val
    )t
    GROUP BY t.id, t.val
    HAVING t.id > max( t.val )

Comment: @Deonis - Угу, видимо мускул хавает но ничего не выводит, а вот посгрес умный:

>ERROR:  column "t.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select  t.id as  id , t.val as val from

Comment: а можно ссылку на документацию где написано о having  и group by?
А на счет MySQL уже неоднократно были случаи, что она хавает то, что не должно работать.

Comment: [Вот тут][1] кое-что описывает данную ситуацию.

> In standard SQL, a query that includes
> a GROUP BY clause cannot refer to
> nonaggregated columns in the HAVING
> clause that are not named in the GROUP
> BY clause.

   [1]:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что вы хотели получить что-то типа:

```
select  t.id as  id , t.val as val from
(
 select 1 id, 2 val union all
 select 2 id, 2 val union all
 select 3 id, 4 val union all
 select 4 id, 1 val union all
 select 5 id, 1 val union all
 select 6 id, 3 val
)t
where t.id>(select max(t.val) from
(
 select 1 id, 2 val union all
 select 2 id, 2 val union all
 select 3 id, 4 val union all
 select 4 id, 1 val union all
 select 5 id, 1 val union all
 select 6 id, 3 val
)t
);
```

Конечно, можно использовать диалектические нарушающие стандарт вещи, но я бы предпочел, чтобы MySQL поддерживал стандартные [общие табличные выражения](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_common_table_expressions_cte.html) и [оконные функции](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_window_functions.html). Тогда не пришлось бы дублировать код, и он бы работал под другими СУБД.